# how to prevent drawing polygons on an existing shapes layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have recently started working on web mapping with leaflet js 1.0 . I started working with leaflet-draw but I don't find a solution to prevent drawing a polygon over any other polygon or intersects with another one from an existing layer.

I tried the allow intersection option but it didn't detect, and also i didn't find any real examples of how to prevent drawing a shape over an existing one from another layer.

I expect the output to be

Comment: This (probably) isn't an answer to your question, but leaflet v 1.0 is nearly 3 years old - unless you've a very good reason not to, you should start with the latest version (1.5.1 as I write this)